# JQuery / Smarty: variable within .keyUp is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, undefined, onkeyup

So basically, I'm creating variables within the keyUp method of input box that get their data from a smarty loop (this is within the `$(document.ready)`

Here is the code

```
{section name=unitEl loop=$allNavies}
    $("#attack-navy{$allNavies[unitEl].ID}-number").keyup(function(){
        var unit = {$allNavies[unitEl]};
        var element = $("#attack-navy" + unit.ID + "-number");
        var available_count = {$NAVY_{$allNavies[unitEl].ID}_AVAILABLE_COUNT|default:'0'};
        alert(unit.ID);
        // Unit max = available count
        if(element.val() > available_count)
        {
            completeUnitValue(element, available_count);
        }
        // If transport navy: Increase capacity
        if({$allNavies[unitEl].ID} == 16 || {$allNavies[unitEl].ID} == 19 || {$allNavies[unitEl].ID} == 20)
        {
            $("#attack-max-capacity").text(getMaxCapacity());
        }
    });
{/section}
```

The problem is, when I alert any of the variables (unit, element, available_count) I receive undefined, but when i use the smarty `{$allNavies[unitEl]}` instead of variables, everything works fine. I just created variables to make the code more readable.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call what you're doing "smarvascript".  I loathe it and beg my coworkers to avoid it. But then, I loathe Smarty altogether, so there ya go.

This line:

```
var unit = {$allNavies[unitEl]};
```

assigns some PHP value into a JS var.

This line:

```
alert(unit.ID);
```

makes it look like you believe 'unit' is an object with properties. You cannot directly assign a PHP object into a JS object and expect it to work...

I'd need to see some of your PHP code and data structures to explain how you *should* do it, but it is possible that this might help

```
var unit = {$allNavies[unitEl]|json_encode};
```

Or, if $allNavies[unitEl] is an array:

```
var unit = {$allNavies[unitEl]|@json_encode};
```

I could probably help most if I knew what the structure of $allNavies was.

Also, I am curious...where are your {literal} markings to keep the JS curly braces from making Smarty freak out?

**Edit:**

Here is a little trick I like to use when I am forced into injecting Smarty into JS:

```
//{literal}
( function( allNavies )
{
    /*
      allNavies is now a JS object and you can work purely with JS in here
     */
}(
    //{/literal}
    {$allNavies|@json_encode}
    //{literal}
) );
//{/literal}
```

Comment: I tried setting the {$allNavies[unitEl].ID} into the unit variable instead of the object - still undefined

Comment: The only way 'unit.id' is gonna be set is if you set 'unit' to an empty object ({}), then assign $allNavies[unitEl].ID into 'unit.id'. Or if you use some JSON encoding like I mentioned. Can you tell me what sort of structure $allNavies is?

Comment: its just an associative array, if i use the $allNavies with smarty + javascript as a method parameter it works well, unless i try to store it in a variable. Im begging to think it has something to do with document.ready. I'm new to jquery / ajax so I have no idea :(.

Comment: I don't have much info about literal markings and such (i dont even know what they are) im new here just fixing bugs. Maybe it works because it is not a javascript file but a tpl.

Comment: Unfortunately I have several years experience with Smarty use every day. But we're on a pretty old version, I believe. Maybe they've changed something around w/ regard to literals. Anyway, it shouldn't have anything to do with doc-ready as the smarty stuff is PHP and is executed on the server. It would be helpful for you to view source to see what PHP is actually outputting. In the mean time, I'll add an edit to my post based on the assoc array you mention.

Comment: Ok well, finally finished what i was doing so i tried the @json_encode and it got to print the unit.ID no problem. Thanks a bunch!

This worked - 
var unit = {$allNavies[unitEl]|@json_encode};
   alert(unit.ID);

Comment: Ah, good, glad you have it working. See the stuff I added under "Edit" in my answer for a tip. :)